# Animation rotates to closest angle

Tags: animation, armature

I am trying to create an armature animation where the character spins around, but I am having huge issues. If I rotated it from 0° to 360° on another keyframe, then it won't spin at all. If I rotate from 0° to 180°, then from 180° to 360°, the character spins to 180°, then spins backwards to where it started.
How can I make it rotate the amount I want, instead of just rotating in the direction that is closest to the current angle?

Comment: If you rotate the character by pressing `R 360`, blender will actually not rotate the object. Instead try typing the rotation in *3D view > properties region (N) > Transforms*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you rotate an object visually in the 3Dview, the rotation value that is used is not always the value you expect. You can get more predictable results by entering values directly in the properties of the object, which can also be found in the properties sidebar by pressing <kbd>N</kbd>

[image]

When you do have trouble with direction of rotation (or movement), the [graph editor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/Graph) shows you visually how the values are interpreted and gives you full control over the keyframed values.

In this example the rotation goes to 180 then back to 0

[image]

By adjusting the third keyframe we change it to go to 180 then to 360

[image]

You can also change the channels extrapolation (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> or Channel->Extrapolation Mode) to linear and have a constant rotation with only two keyframes.

[image]